# Convergence of a sequence that seems to be Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

The statement is:

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\lvert x_{n+1} - x_n\rvert) =0$, then $x_n$ is a bounded sequence.

This statement is false (counterexample $x_n=\sqrt{n}$), but I would like to consolidate it with my (basic) understanding of Cauchy sequences i.e. I get the feeling that $\lvert x_{n+1} - x_n\rvert$ kind of fits the definition of a Cauchy sequence.  Then wouldn't the fact that it converges imply that it is also bounded?

Comment: Yes. But the Cauchy condition is way more restrictive than the condition you have here. Consider the even more basic example $x_n=n$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cauchy says *all* terms bunch up after a point, not just consecutive ones.  You can't prove that *all* terms get arbitrarily close just by knowing consecutive ones do.  Consider the divergent sum $\sum\frac1n$ for example.

Comment: Thank you! But I dont see how the harmonic series illustrates the point.

Comment: The harmonic series satisfies the condition you gave. Consider $\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Mandralis If you let $s_n$ be the $n$-th partial sum of the harmonic then $|s_n-s_{n+1}|\rightarrow0$ but given $K\in\Bbb N$, no matter how big $N$ is you can still find $n,m>N$ so that $|s_n-s_m|>K$.  So $\langle s_n\rangle$ is not Cauchy.  But you can't find $n$ and $m$ consecutive, they have to get further and further apart as $K$ grows.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is much clearer now.

Comment: @Mandralis No problem I remember having the exact same confusion once, back in the day.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$a_n = \sin\sqrt n$$
The $(a_n)$ sequence bounces between $-1$ and $1$ forever - it is bounded and divergent.
However its differences $$x_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$$ tend to zero:
$$\begin{align}
|x_n| & = |a_{n+1} - a_n| \\
 & = |\sin\sqrt{n+1} - \sin\sqrt n| \\
 & < \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n \\
 & = \frac{(n+1)-n}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt n} \\
 & < \frac 1{2\sqrt n} \\
\end{align}$$